Wordpress Customizr - Post images cropped on first load
I am running a wordpress site with Customizr theme.
When I view a post page, the image gets displayed in cropped mode on the first load - and correctly on reload.
See examples here when you click on one of the posts in this overview:
https://mattenplatz.de/angebot/specials
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Feels like some preloading-setting maybe?
I ttried changing some settings but don´t hget it to work properly.

The cropped display in this overview is correct, that is what I want! Its just about the post page itself!

I think I got it - disabled the "load images on scrolling" option in Customizr - that seems to do the trick.
